# Creating a blackberry app that displays ads

Tags: blackberry

I've created a simple application that displays an advertisement. I used [this article](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/40306/Creating_a_BB_app_that_displays_an_ad_1176551_11.jsp). I followed all steps but I get `NoClassDefFound` error on the BlackBerry 9900 simulator.

**Update**:
    I have used preverify.exe to checks  jar file to be compatible with net_rim_api.jar:
    preverify -classpath "D:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\com
    ponents\lib\net_rim_api" "net_rim_bbapi_adv_app.jar" "D:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack7.1.0_7.1.0.10\components\bin\output"
i am getting like this,what should i do?

```
Error preverifying class net.rimlib.blackberry.api.advertising.app.a
    java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Thread
```

Below, there's my code:

```
        import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
        import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
        import net.rimlib.blackberry.api.advertising.app.Banner;

        public class AdDemo extends UiApplication{
           public static void main(String[] args)
           {
              AdDemo theApp = new AdDemo();
              theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
           }

           public AdDemo()
           {
              pushScreen(new AdDemoScreen());
           }

        }

        class AdDemoScreen extends MainScreen{

           public AdDemoScreen()
           {
               Banner bannerAd = new Banner(16741, null);
               bannerAd.setMMASize(Banner.MMA_SIZE_EXTRA_LARGE);            
               add(bannerAd);
           }

        }
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more information regarding the exception you get. Wich class cannot be found? Provide full qualified name of this class.

Comment: after execution of  my demo app ,i am getting App Error 104 uncaught:NoclassDeffoungError on my screen

Comment: Hii,i executed just now,when i try to click on my app on blackberry screen,i am getting one alert message,it is saying "Error Starting MyProjectName: Module AddsonBlackberry(ProjectName) has verification Errors"?

Comment: Does class name specified in error message?

Comment: Did you add third-party jar-files to your project?

Comment: yes,first i copied to lib folder then i right clicked on jar file and i did add to build path

Comment: i have downloded the jar file from this https://developer.blackberry.com/appworld/advertising

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16905/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-ragi-and-rafael-osipov)